# Bettercap on Mac M1 (zsh killed)

Tags: macos, zsh, apple-m1

I have brew installed on my MacBook Air (M1).
I have also Bettercap installed by `brew install bettercap`. That was successful, but it won't start by the command `bettercap`.
So I have copied and renamed the terminal app with rosetta activated by right click on the icon and checkmarked Rosetta. Trying to start Bettercap by `sudo bettercap` is working now.

BUT: the command `ble.recon on` is showing no result.
`Help` command is showing:

```
       api.rest > not running
      arp.spoof > not running
      ble.recon > not running
             c2 > not running
        caplets > not running
    dhcp6.spoof > not running
      dns.spoof > not running
  events.stream > running
            gps > not running
            hid > not running
     http.proxy > not running
    http.server > not running
    https.proxy > not running
   https.server > not running
    mac.changer > not running
    mdns.server > not running
   mysql.server > not running
      ndp.spoof > not running
      net.probe > not running
      net.recon > not running
      net.sniff > not running
   packet.proxy > not running
       syn.scan > not running
      tcp.proxy > not running
         ticker > not running
             ui > not running
         update > not running
           wifi > not running
            wol > not running
```

`Help MODULE` is showing:

```
[01:58:45] [sys.log] [err] module MODULE not found
```

Is there anything missing or is it just not supported for M1 Macs by now?

Comment: `wifi.recon on` is activating WIFI, but no results either.

Comment: same for me ble doesnt work